# Facebook query for commenter name not working

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a problem retrieving information regarding the person commenting on the post using the graph API. I'm retriving as follow.

```
/comment-id?fields=message,from
```

Comment: Why down vote? the similar question was asked one month ago and the api is changed just today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11#gapi-90-pages:

> /page/* — User information will not be included in GET responses for any objects owned by (on) a Page unless the request is made with a Page access token. This affects all nodes and edges that return data for objects owned by a Page.